# OSError: [Errno 22] invalid argument socket python socket

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have some app that use UDP socket. Each app can to send and receive date.
In an app that recevie data, code is below:
receiver app:

```py
UDPSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
bufferSize= 1024
EnginePort=2000


def ReceiveSocket():
    global UDPSocket
    global AddressPort
    global bufferSize
    AddressPort   = ("127.0.0.2", EnginePort)
    # Bind to address and ip
    UDPSocket.bind(AddressPort)
    print("UDP server up and listening")
    bytesAddressPair = UDPSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    message = pickle.loads(bytesAddressPair[0])
    address = bytesAddressPair[1]
    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    clientIP  = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)
    print(clientMsg)
    print(clientIP)


while True:
    ReceiveSocket()
```

sending  a simple message:

```py
import socket
import pickle
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.2"
UDP_PORT = 2000
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

print ("UDP target IP:", UDP_IP)
print ("UDP target port:", UDP_PORT)
print ("message:", MESSAGE)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(pickle.dumps(MESSAGE), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

When receive data ,give me this error:
receiver output:

```py
Message from Client:Hello, World!
Client IP Address:('127.0.0.2', 2003)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/RoomServerTestApps/Engine.py", line 88, in <module>
    ReceiveSocket()
  File "/home/pi/RoomServerTestApps/Engine.py", line 29, in ReceiveSocket
    UDPSocket.bind(AddressPort)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

But when the `ReceiveSocket()` is outside the `while true()`, app work well.
Please help me about this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get bind() out of the loop. You've already bound to the port at first run, that's why the second+ run fails.

```py
AddressPort   = ("127.0.0.2", EnginePort)
UDPSocket.bind(AddressPort)
def ReceiveSocket():
...
```